# How to create dynamic nested accordion in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, accordion

How i can create an accordion like this

```
-parent
   -subparent1
      -subparent2
        ...
          -subparentN
             - child
```

Here is my data.

```
//parents
{id: 1, name: "", parent_id: null}
{id: 2, name: "", parent_id: null }
{id: 3, name: "", parent_id: null }
{id: 4, name: "", parent_id: null}

//children
{id: 5, name: "", parent_id: 1}
{id: 6, name: "", parent_id: 1}
{id: 7, name: "", parent_id: 5}
{id: 8, name: "", parent_id: 5}
{id: 9, name: "", parent_id: 6}
{id: 10, name: "", parent_id: 6}
{id: 11, name: "", parent_id: 6}
{id: 12, name: "", parent_id: 6}
{id: 13,name: "", parent_id: 6}
{id: 14, name: "", parent_id: 6}
```

Basically the ones who have parent_id:null are parents, and when I click on them I want their potential children to be displayed if they have any, now this isn't that hard, but what I can't understand is how to display subparent's children

Comment: create subparent children as a component with own state open/close and then propagate it on click, should be the same as you did for parent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your data structure should be a nested object similarly to how you see your menu working, i.e.

```
[
    {id: 1, name:"", children: [
      {id: 5, name: "", children: []},
      {id: 6, name: "", children: [
        {id: 7, name: "", children: []},
        {id: 8, name: "", children: []},
      ]},
    ]},
    {id: 2, name:"", children:[]}
]
```

Then you would need a function to output each item:

```
const returnMenuItem = (item, i) =>{
  let menuItem;

  if (item.children.length===0) {
    menuItem = <div key={i}>{item.label}</div>;
  }
  else {
    let menuItemChildren = item.children.map((item,i)=>{
      let menuItem = returnMenuItem(item,i);
      return menuItem;
    });
    menuItem = <div key={i}>
      <div>{item.label}</div>
      <div>
        {menuItemChildren}
      </div>
    </div>;
  }
  return menuItem;
}
```

And you would invoke this function by going through your items:

```
let menuItems = data.map((item,i)=>{
    let menuItem = returnMenuItem(item,i);
    return menuItem;
});
```

A complete component would look something like the following:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { UncontrolledCollapse } from "reactstrap";

const Menu = (props) => {

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
  const [items, setItems] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    const menuData = [
      {
        id: 1,
        name: "test 1",
        children: [
          { id: 5, name: "test 5", children: [] },
          {
            id: 6,
            name: "test 6",
            children: [
              { id: 7, name: "test 7", children: [] },
              { id: 8, name: "test 8", children: [] }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      { id: 2, name: "test 2", children: [] }
    ];
    const returnMenuItem = (item, i) => {
      let menuItem;

      if (item.children.length === 0) {
        menuItem = (
          <div className="item" key={i}>
            {item.name}
          </div>
        );
      } else {
        let menuItemChildren = item.children.map((item, i) => {
          let menuItem = returnMenuItem(item, i);
          return menuItem;
        });
        menuItem = (
          <div key={i} className="item">
            <div className="toggler" id={`toggle-menu-item-${item.id}`}>
              {item.name}
            </div>
            <UncontrolledCollapse
              className="children"
              toggler={`#toggle-menu-item-${item.id}`}
            >
              {menuItemChildren}
            </UncontrolledCollapse>
          </div>
        );
      }
      return menuItem;
    };

    const load = async () => {
      setLoading(false);
      let menuItems = menuData.map((item, i) => {
        let menuItem = returnMenuItem(item, i);
        return menuItem;
      });
      setItems(menuItems);
    };
    if (loading) {
      load();
    }
  }, [loading]);

  return <div className="items">{items}</div>;
};
export default Menu;
```

And a minimum css:

```
.item {
  display: block;
}
.item > .children {
  padding: 0 0 0 40px;
}
.item > .toggler {
  display: inline-block;
}

.item::before {
  content: "-";
  padding: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

You can find a working code sandbox here [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-sunset-oy2i8?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: hi, great answer, it works if i want to display all elements, but how i'd do something like an accordion? I want to press the parent and have the children collapse.

Comment: I normally use reactstrap as a react-bootstrap package. I then wrap my menu in a Nav (https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navs/) and the menu items that have children in an UncontrolledDropdown element (https://reactstrap.github.io/components/dropdowns/). Finally for the items i use the NavItem element. If you want to go with an accordion approach you can wrap your items with children in a collapse (https://reactstrap.github.io/components/collapse/). If you find this difficult or are unsure how to use this describe in detail the expected behaviour and I can expand my answer to cover that.

Comment: yes please. I am lost on how to make it work with the returnMenuItem function that you were so kind to provide.Thanks a lot, all this nesting and recursion makes me dizzy

Comment: I updated my answer with an example component. You should have all you need now to build a component according to your needs.

Comment: Cheers, always happy to help. If it's what you wanted then you should check this as the right answer.

Comment: What if I want to show Plus (+) and Minus(-) sign respectively? for now it shows only minus sign. @StavrosAngelis

Comment: You can add a new key "expanded" to each item and if true show a plus icon, else show a minus icon. Then onClick update the state items to reflect that and you are good to go.

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the list of all your items and add each sub item to their parent. Afterwards you just have to loop over all the items in the array and create their respective html.

```js
const items = [
  //parents
  {id: 1, name: "1", parent_id: null},
  {id: 2, name: "2", parent_id: null },
  {id: 3, name: "3", parent_id: null },
  {id: 4, name: "4", parent_id: null},

  //children
  {id: 5, name: "5", parent_id: 1},
  {id: 6, name: "6", parent_id: 1},
  {id: 7, name: "7", parent_id: 5},
  {id: 8, name: "8", parent_id: 5},
  {id: 9, name: "9", parent_id: 6},
  {id: 10, name: "10", parent_id: 6},
  {id: 11, name: "11", parent_id: 6},
  {id: 12, name: "12", parent_id: 6},
  {id: 13,name: "13", parent_id: 6},
  {id: 14, name: "14", parent_id: 6},
];

for(const item of items) {
  // Find the parent object
  const parent = items.find(({ id }) => id === item.parent_id);
  // If the parent is found add the object to its children array
  if(parent) {
    parent.children = parent.children ? [...parent.children, item] : [item]
  }
};

// Only keep root elements (parents) in the main array
const list = items.filter(({ parent_id }) => !parent_id);

// console.log(list);

// Show tree (vanillaJS, no REACT)
for(const item of list) {
  // Create a new branch for each item
  const ul = createBranch(item);
  // Append branch to the document
  document.body.appendChild(ul);
}

function createBranch(item) {
  // Create ul item for each branch
  const ul = document.createElement("ul");
  // Add current item as li to the branch
  const li = document.createElement("li");
  li.textContent = item.name;
  ul.appendChild(li);

  // Check if there are children
  if(item.children) {
    // Create a new branch for each child
    for(const child of item.children) {
      const subUl = createBranch(child);
      // Append child branch to current branch
      ul.appendChild(subUl);
    }
  }
  
  return ul;
}
```

```css
ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding-left: 2rem;
}
```

Comment: you are an absolute beast, real genius, thank you so so much, you are a life saver.I would've never came even close to this myself. By the way, i have another layer of children and it works all the same, thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I think that your data structure has a flaw. Beside child to parent relation, you should keep track of parent to child relationship. Now you will be able to easily iterate through the data and render sub parent's children.

```js
{id: 1, parent_id: null, children: [
  {id: 2, parent_id: 1, children: []},
  {id: 3, parent_id: 1, children: [
    {id: 4, parent_id: 3, children: []}
  ]}
]}
```

If you need to keep all objects inline, you can structure your data like:

```js
{id: 1, parent_id: null, children: [2, 3]}
{id: 2, parent_id: 1, children: []},
{id: 3, parent_id: 1, children: [4]},
{id: 4, parent_id: 3, children: []}
```